# How to use existing polygon feature class as training samples in ArcGIS Pro Classification Wizard?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, classification, land-classification, image-classification

I have created a polygon feature class from field observations at specific locations. I renamed the attribute table field containing the classes to "classname" as this seems to be important for training samples. Next, I created a new field "classvalue" using the "Calculate field" function to assign a unique classvalue for each classname based on my classification schema.

Thus, I have a polygon feature class layer with the fields "classname" and "classvalue" that should now be suitable training samples. I specified my polygon feature class as input to "training samples" in the first tab of the Classification Wizard under "Optional".

However, in the next tab "Training Samples Manager" it lists all observations instead of aggregating the individual samples for each class.

Does someone know why the individual samples are understood as classes by the Training Samples Manager instead of aggregating them by classname?